# No module named virtualenvwrapper when open the command line window(Ubuntu)

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda

[my command line window(picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjYEI.jpg)

No VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON when I run `printenv` . This happened after I updated my system(Ubuntu) if my memory serves me well.

when I run `whereis virtualenvwrapper` it shows `virtualenvwrapper: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

When I run `whereis virtualenv` it shows `virtualenv: /usr/bin/virtualenv /usr/share/man/man1/virtualenv.1.gz`

What should I do to make things right?

Answer (score 0):

/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh is a collection of shell functions to include into shell. But there have to be a virtualenvwrapper python module installed into site-packages. You have to install it into the same python — conda's python in your case. I think you've installed it currently with system python (/usr/bin/python).